# argparse.add_argument() default always used... sometimes

Tags: python, argparse

This simplified script is enough to cause the issue... just checking if the '-d' argument is a valid directory, supplying a default if it's not provided...

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import argparse

def valid(dir):
   subdir = dir + '/Desktop'
   if not os.path.exists(subdir):
      raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError("%s is not a valid directory" % subdir)
   return dir

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="blah blah blah")
parser.add_argument('-d', '--directory', help='directory to check', default=os.getcwd(), type=valid)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

And it doesn't matter what the default argument is, when I run the script it uses the default, no matter what I enter on the command line, and throws an uncaught exception as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./parsertest.py", line 15, in <module>
    args = parser.parse_args()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1688, in parse_args
    args, argv = self.parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1710, in parse_known_args
    default = self._get_value(action, default)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 2239, in _get_value
    raise ArgumentError(action, msg)
argparse.ArgumentError: argument -d/--directory: /home/users/jrice/Desktop/Desktop is not a valid directory
```

Runs fine, and by fine I mean, handles the ArgumentTypeError as and when it should, just printing the msg when if I do the following:

1. Remove the 'default=' argument
2. Do not append '/Desktop' to dir, so subdir = dir, or just check dir itself
3. Run the script from my home directory!?!?

Elaboration: If I do any of the above, even if '-d' isn't valid, everything is fine.  This is the output, which is what I want.

```
>./Desktop/parsertest.py -d blah
usage: parsertest.py [-h] [-d DIRECTORY]
parsertest.py: error: argument -d/--directory: blah/Desktop is not a valid directory
```

why should os.getcwd() + '/Desktop' be any different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Argparse attempts to convert the default argument to whatever type was given to it.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="blah blah blah")
parser.add_argument('-i',default="1",type=int)

args = parser.parse_args([])
print args          # Namespace(i=1)
print type(args.i)  # <type 'int'>
```

The reason for this design choice is a little weird to me, but it is probably so that you can pass strings to `default` just as it would get them on the commandline and then the help will be formatted properly.

Note I don't really like passing validation code to the `type` keyword argument even though they do it in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#type).  That argument is to convert the input string into some other type.  If you really want to do the validation as you parse, you should consider using a custom `Action`, but for this example, it's probably just easiest to do:

```
#...snip...
parser.add_argument('-d', '--directory', help='directory to check')
args = parser.parse_args()
args.directory = valid(args.directory if args.directory is not None else os.getcwd())
#the following should work too. 
#args.directory = valid(args.directory if args.directory else os.getcwd())
```

Comment: As far as it not making sense to pass validation code to the type keyword, it's documented here, [http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#type] if I am understanding it, and you correctly.

Comment: @JimiChanga -- I don't really like that example, but you're right.  It *can* be used for type checking, but only if a passable default is guaranteed.  In their example with `perfect_square`, the input argument is a positional argument which means that it is **required**.  In that case, it makes sense to do conversion and checking at the same time because they're guaranteed to have something to check.  Of course, this brings up the question, what should happen if `os.getcwd()` doesn't have a `Desktop` subdirectory?  Why should that special case pass?

Comment: @JimiChanga -- I've updated my answer slightly in light of your link.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I don't think it should matter if os.getcwd() doesn't have a Desktop subdirectory, os.path.exists() should return false, and then the exception thrown, and handled as in the example.

Comment: @JimiChanga -- Hold on, I thought the problem was that that case doesn't pass when it should?  Can you edit the question to make it a little more explicit about what your actual problem is?

Comment: @JimiChanga -- Sorry, after re-reading your question, I think I know what your problem is.  I made a slight modification to my second piece of code to reflect my new understanding.

Comment: Yes, you mostly got it, then I actually have a second check in the real script, which is to check if this is a particular kind of directory by checking it's sub-directories, thus the + "/Desktop".  Again, not the real script, I gutted/simplified it, to find the problem and make it clearer here.

Answer (score 3):

I believe your "type checking" is too aggressive. You treat a non-existing directory as an invalid type, which is not the way `argparse` has been thought. In your case, the default value might not be a "valid type" which confuses argparse. Check out the following code and its output:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import argparse

def valid(dir):
   print "Checking " + dir
   subdir = dir + '/Desktop'
   #if not os.path.exists(subdir):
   #   raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError("%s is not a valid directory" % subdir)
   return dir

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="blah blah blah")
parser.add_argument('-d', '--directory', help='directory to check', type=valid, default=os.getcwd())
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Executing it from `/home/user/Desktop` with `-d /home/user` gives:

```
Checking /home/user/Desktop
Checking /home/user
```

As you can see, `argparse` first converts the default value and only then the command-line given value.

To solve the above issue, either make sure that the default value is always a "valid type" or that you check the directory after `argparse` is done.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It doesn't matter if it's a valid type os.getcwd() should always return a valid directory, and 'default=/tmp' does the same thing, even though /tmp is valid.

Comment: Actually, it's not correct to assume os.getcwd() always returns a valid directory. Sometimes it raises FileNotFoundError instead. Consider what happens when I make a directory /tmp/foo, `cd` to it, and launch `python`. I check that `os.getcwd()` returns `'/tmp/foo'`. Then I switch to another terminal and `rmdir /tmp/foo`. `os.getcwd()` will now raise FileNotFoundError when I next call it in the Python session.